# Naming conventions on IBAction functions

Tags: iphone, ios, ibaction

I am doing another iOS application and I wonder if there are any naming conventions or good practices on how to name actions that I could follow. I am thinking of names on the functions that are invoked when user e.g. touches a button.

Answer (score 25):

Go with Apple's guidelines.  What were in the past good suggestions have now been codified in ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) and are necessary to be followed for ARC to generate correct code.  Using these guidelines may well future-proof your code, it did for ARC!

Apple's guidelines
[Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH)

From the method naming section:

Start the name with a lowercase letter and capitalize the first letter of embedded words. Don’t use prefixes.

There are two specific exceptions to these guidelines. You may begin a method name with a well-known acronym in uppercase (such as TIFF or PDF)), and you may use prefixes to group and identify private methods

For methods that represent actions an object takes, start the name with a verb.

```
- (void)invokeWithTarget:(id)target;
- (void)selectTabViewItem:(NSTabViewItem *)tabViewItem
```

Do not use “do” or “does” as part of the name because these auxiliary verbs rarely add meaning. Also, never use adverbs or adjectives before the verb.

If the method returns an attribute of the receiver, name the method after the attribute. The use of “get” is unnecessary, unless one or more values are returned indirectly.

```
- (NSSize)cellSize;
```

Use keywords before all arguments.

```
- (void)sendAction:(SEL)aSelector to:(id)anObject forAllCells:(BOOL)flag
```

Make the word before the argument describe the argument.

```
- (id)viewWithTag:(int)aTag;
```

Comment: I think you meant "have now been codified."

Comment: Does not answer the question, which is specifically about IBAction.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't come across much in the way of specifics when it comes to naming conventions for IBActions.  However, if you were to follow the trend Apple seems to be setting in its sample apps, then some examples are as follows:

```
-(IBAction)cameraAction:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Apple's sample code is responsible for so many bad practices. Only use it to see how framework code works. Do *not* take coding style or design patterns from it.

Answer (score 4):

I guess any method name in Objective - C should be readable like you reading an english sentence. Lets say below method.

```
[fileWrapper writeToFile: path atomically: YES updateFilenames: YES]; 
// This is not a real example but purpose of sharing is to make sure 
   method name is readable, so programmers can actually read code and can
   have SmallTalk.
```

When you read left to right it helps you to read and explains it self what it is going to do.

Check out this below link,

http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php

```
Jump on page No. 5 of 7
```

There are lots of tips has been given. More tips can be found in Apple's developer library.

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://blog.cocoafrog.de/2018/04/12/How-to-name-IBActions.html) is a discussion about how to name `IBAction` functions/methods.